# Heroku - Rails/React - ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, heroku

I've just added a couple of react libraries to my app, and when I install them locally it all seems okay since I ran `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps`, but when I push to heroku, I get the following error.

```
-----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: react-spring-pop@1.3.2
remote:        npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"16.8.x" from react-konva@16.8.6
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/react-konva
remote:        npm ERR!     peer react-konva@"^16.8.0  || ^17.0.0" from @react-spring/konva@9.5.2
remote:        npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-spring/konva
remote:        npm ERR!       @react-spring/konva@"~9.5.2" from react-spring@9.5.2
remote:        npm ERR!       node_modules/react-spring
remote:        npm ERR!         react-spring@"^9.5.2" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote:        npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-spring-pop@1.3.2
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react-spring-pop
remote:        npm ERR!   react-spring-pop@"^1.3.2" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-spring-pop@1.3.2
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/react-spring-pop
remote:        npm ERR!     react-spring-pop@"^1.3.2" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
remote:        npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
remote:        npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! See FILE for a full report.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     LINK.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

My `package.json` is the following:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "NAME",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/sxtimulus": "^3.1.0",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.1.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.54",
    "github-calendar": "^2.3.1",
    "node": "^18.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-spring": "^9.5.2",
    "react-spring-pop": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.7.0",
    "npm": "8.16.0"
  },
    "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild --bundle app/javascript/main.js --outfile=app/assets/javascripts/application.js",
    "watch": "esbuild --watch --bundle app/javascript/main.js --outfile=app/assets/javascripts/application.js"
  }
}
```

I've checked that my local node and npm versions match `package.json` `"engines"`

I'm guessing that this is because the `--legacy-peer-deps` is `true` locally, but not on heroku, but I don't know how to force this in heroku upon deployment.

Any assistance is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  You can add config variables in Heroku apps.

Go to the app in Heroku -> `settings` -> `Reveal Config Vars`

Add a new config var with the key: `NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS` and value `true`, and then redeploy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).